# Get the sum of the colunm with specific id from one table and get the details from another table with that id in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to get the sum of the column with specific `id` from one table and get the details from another table with that `id` with mysql query and codeigniter.
I have used this code:

```
function total_commision($ids)
{
    $values=array();
    for($o=0;$o<count($ids);$o++) {
        $this->db->select('SUM(commision) AS total_commision', FALSE);
        $this->db->where('hierarchy_users_id',$ids[$o]);
        $query = $this->db->get('commision');
        $value=$query->result()[0];
        array_push($values, $value);
    }
    return $values;
  }
```

I want to get the details of each member  from the another table with that `id` in database using codeigniter query .

Comment: You are missing the `from` clause. By the way, what is the problem you are facing? Some error? Which?

Comment: i wants to get details from another table with that id..how to change this query..

Comment: You did not answer my questions. Nor read what I told you are missing...

Comment: sorry..from clause is missing.but the table name is in the get clause..

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following

```
function total_commision($ids)
{
    $query = $this->db
        ->select('SUM(commision) AS total_commision, admin_credentials.*', FALSE)
        ->from("commision")
        ->join("admin_credentials", "admin_credentials.id = commision.hierarchy_users_id", "left")
        ->where_in('commision.hierarchy_users_id', $ids)
        ->group_by('commision.hierarchy_users_id')
        ->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: think about your comment pls - how should i do that if you don't provide any details about what you want ? .... (table name or schema, related keys, example data and the most important thing - what did you try ?)

Comment: sorry.i have a table admin_credentials..wants to get all details of above mentioned ids from this table . above query and this have to done in single function.

Comment: how does your table `admin_credentials` look like ?

Comment: id | name | username | email | password | this is my table.the id and hierarchy_users_id are same...

Comment: in that case - this is a simple join - i updated my answer

Comment: did you get what you want ?

Comment: i've updated my answer - whats wrong about that (did you even try it) ?

Comment: i have tried that but getting error ;  Column 'hierarchy_users_id' in where clause is ambiguous  @sintakote